# Multiple Loader animations using Microfrontend

Tags: javascript, web, frontend, web-frontend, micro-frontend

**Motiviation:**
I'm running a container application hosting a couple of different frontend applications.
Today, I have a loader animation for every single application and a loader animation for my host container app like in scenario A.
I'm looking for a way to sync between the different loader animations for each app w/o interrupting any functionality of the host container, like header functionality, i.e the host container loader will load the infrastructure and then will be used by the different applications aka fragments with the ability to use the host container functionality like navigation, menu etc...

**DOD:**
The required result is to present only the host container loader animation syncing with the different applications loaders and allow to interact with the host container functionality even before the different applications were loaded.

**Open issue:**
What would happen in case the host container didn't finish loading all the functionality needed, but the presented apps were loaded?

**My question is:**
I would be happy to hear some advice on how to achieve one loader animation for microfrontend application including host container app combined with fragments apps.
The different applications can include a dedicated loader animation, but when there is a loader for the host container, only one Loader animation should appear.

Good Scenario could be:
Scenario B - The host container finishes loading, and different apps are loading.
Scenario C - All the Parts are loading - Host container and different apps.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQeRt.png)

**What did i try to do?**
Every application is using a loader animation to load each screen/page.
Once the screen/page is loaded, the loader animation is set to off.
The host container is having a dedicated loader animation and it is set to off when all the data related to host container functionality is loaded, like user data (Theme, name, rank, and every visual aspect on the header), every element that is not shown on the host container first rendering like menu items, are loaded with lazy loading.